# Siddhi polling interval on sqs source not working

Tags: amazon-sqs, siddhi

Hi I'm new to Siddhi and have set up an app with a SQS source, I've tried setting the polling interval to 10 seconds and the Max number of messages to 1.

However I just get a constant stream of messages as if it is just ignoring the values.

Here's my code with sensitive info removed

---

```
@App:name('SQS TEST')
@App:description('Description of the plan')

@source(type = 'sqs', 
    queue = '',
    access.key = '',
    secret.key = '',
    region = '',
    polling.interval = '10000',
    wait.time = '20',
    max.number.of.messages = '1',
    delete.messages='false', 
    number.of.parallel.consumers = '1',
    @map(type = 'json', fail.on.missing.attribute='false', enclosing.element='$.entries',
        @attributes(val1 = 'val1', val2='val2')))

define stream inStream (val1 string, val2 string);

@sink(type = 'log', prefix = 'Cafe Feed:')
define stream log_received (val1 string, val2 string);

from inStream
select val1,val2
insert into log_received;
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for the SQS source is to pull messages from the sqs queue until there are no messages left in the queue the amazon API allows the devs to define the number of messages retrieved per request the above `'max.number.of.messages'` exposes that property.

To overcome this issue you can fix the visibility timeout of the queue to a greater value to stop the messages from being returned or delete a message after reading from the queue.